# Return string if it contains specific word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, strpos

I have a string. I want to write a script in PHP for return a string if it has specific characters.

For example: "Hi, this is the sample.png" is a string. Now I want to output as "Hi, this is the".

I.e., if the string contains .jpg, .png, then I need to replace those words from a string.

This is my sample code:

```
$output = preg_replace('/.png/', '$1','Hi, this is the sample.png');
print_r($output);exit;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace` function with a specific regex pattern:

```
$str = 'Hi, this is the sample_test.png (or, perhaps, sample_test.jpg)';
$output = preg_replace('/\b[\w_]+\.(png|jpg)\b/', '', $str);

print_r($output);    // "Hi, this is the  (or, perhaps, )"
```

If you suppose some other characters to be a part of the "crucial words" - just add them into a character class `[\w_ <other characters>]`

Comment: if the string contains sample_test.png, then your code replace only test.png. but I want to replace sample_test.png

Comment: @Guru, ok, see my update

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a regex, perhaps something like this?

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^ ]+.png/', '$1','Hi, this is the sample.png');
$output2 = preg_replace('/[^ ]+.jpg/', '$1','Hi, this is the sample.jpg');
print_r($output);
print_r($output2);
```